# FinTS 2.2 (HBCI 2.2) VERIFY command returning 69 85

Tags: smartcard, apdu, smartcard-reader, onlinebanking

I am stuck while trying to verify the PIN of a German Bank card (Type=1, DDV, FINTS 2.2). In the following listing, the messages sent to the card are preceded by '->', the answer by '<-. The following steps describe what I have done.

- Check correct ATR to verify that the expected card is inserted
- APDU command "Select Root"

  ```
  -> 00 a4 00 0c 3f00
  <- 9000
  ```
- APDU command "Select File DF_BANKING_20"

  ```
  -> 00 a4 04 0c 09 d27600002548420200
  <- 9000
  ```
- APDU command "Read record from selected file" which is EF_ID. This returns a record with information like card number, currency, ...

  ```
  -> 00 b2 01 cc 00
  <- 90 00
  ```
- Next step should be "Verify". Assume we have a HBCI-PIN 12345. This has to be converted into a "Format 2 Pin" which would be **25 12 34 5f ff ff ff ff**. The
  resulting APDU command is

  ```
  -> 00 20 00 81 08 25 12 34 5f ff ff ff ff
  -> 6985
  ```

The response code means "Conditions not satisfied". So it is not a pin verification error. It looks that I have missed some command to fulfill all conditions needed.

Any tips would be much valued.

Comment: I think I should add some information about the development environment: MacOS 10.11, Eclipse and Java-SE-1.8 with javax.smartcardio and a ReinerSCT card terminal.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of specs at the official HBCI site: https://www.hbci-zka.de/ including PIN procedures and card processing flows.

Ensure that your card supports **Offline-Plain-PIN** Verification to process it directly with card.

Could be **Online-PIN** (Enciphered) or **Offline-Enciphered-PIN** options.

Comment: Thank you. I do have checked all the documents at https://www.hbci-zka.de/ but I have not seen any documentation about the options you have mentioned. Do you have a link for that as well?